# what is the best why to prevent users insert bad code?

Tags: php

I build a site for programme language tutorials , I allow users insert codes from any language, php ,c++ , v...etc ,
so what is the safe way to insert and display codes ? like our site stackoverflow ? is htmlspecialchars() for insert and htmlspecialchars_decode() for display enough ?

Comment: If you encode it on insert and decode it on display, you're basically using the exact content the user wrote, which will open you up to security issues (like XSS attacks etc). Don't encode it on insert (assuming you mean into DB?). Save it "as is" (using Prepared Statements to prevent SQL injections) and encode the data everytime you output it, using [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or similar.

Comment: https://www.tinywebhut.com/display-html-in-web-pages-14

Comment: if I use `htmlspecialchars()` the code not disply good !

Comment: Use `htmlentities()` before inserting and fetch without doing anything.

Comment: ok thanks I should use `htmlentities()` , its only safe ?

Comment: @Saral - You should always strive to store data as pure as possible. You should only encode data before you _use_ it. Data needs to be encoded differently depending on what you're going to do with it. If you encode it on insert, it will be a pain (and in worse case, impossible) to sort it out if you decide to do something different with it that needs a different encoding at a later point.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I used syntaxhighlighter  to make code colored ....so when I use htmlentities() to display code the code will not be display good !

Comment: @kimo - You should be fine using htmlentities() when displaying the code on the web. However, you should do some research on the subject. There are _many_ guides/articles out there that goes in to this in great detail and I would suggest that you study a bunch to learn what the threats and preventions are.

Comment: _"the code will not be display good !"_ - I have no idea what that means or why that happens in your case. If you have an issue with that, create a new question, add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (that includes your code, the expected output, what output your currently getting and a detailed explanation)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok thanks

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, both functions are the options but `htmlspecialchars()` is more preferred if you only need to convert certain characters having special significance in HTML. That may lead `htmlspecialchars()` to be more preferred.

Comment: @Saral - That's why I wrote _"or similar"_ in my first comment. I'm not making any claim that the OP should use one over the other. My reply to the OP was on a direct question about htmlentiteis() (which will be perfectly fine in most situations).